# Buffering Micro-SD data for power saving useful?

Tags: memory, low-power, flash, sd, microsd

I have a datalogger which has only 4KB of SRAM, and because of that it needs to flush its buffer to MicroSD every second. Would adding external SRAM to create a larger buffer safe any significant power? Because when I look into Sandisk's datasheets it says that their cards go into sleep-mode after 5 ms. So it seems there would be no difference in writing every second vs. writing once in 30 seconds? However everything I've hearded untill now seems to contradict that.

Comment: Data sheet for the part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 numbers you need:

A. Power when writing. Assumed 200 mA.

B. Power when not in sleep mode, but not writing.

C. Power when in sleep mode. Assumed 300 uA.

D. Time to perform a write

Power = Voltage * (A*D + (5 ms-D) * B + 995 mS * C).

If D ~ 5 ms; A is dominant.